# Load Images from Parse with ParseQueryFactory upon OnSetClickListener

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I created my ParseQueryFactory. I want to view the list of options available on Parse cloud. When the user clicks on the desired option I want to download images from the parse based on the options provided.

```
final FilterQueryAdapter filterQueryAdapter = new FilterQueryAdapter(this, FilterQueryAdapter.FilterViewHolder.class, new ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.QueryFactory() {

    public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
        ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Places");
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        query.whereNear("GeoArea", userLocation); //column as location
        query.whereWithinKilometers("GeoArea", userLocation, 5);
        //query.include("user");
        query.orderByDescending("PlaceName");
        query.setLimit(6);
        return query;
    }
});

private void setupPhotoFilters() {
    rvFilters.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvFilters.setAdapter(filterQueryAdapter);
    rvFilters.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
}
```

`rvFilters` is the recyclerview which has been assigned with ParseQueryFactory.
`rvFilters` contains Items in a `ViewHolder` `FrameLayout` as `CouponViews` for Each Item. I have `CouponViews` assigned to `OnClick`. I want the user to download when he clicks on the ViewHolder CouponViews.

```
@OnClick(R.id.coupon_view)
public void onCouponViewClick() {

}
```